# RegEx for finding all files that start with any letter followed by a number

Tags: regex, bash, sed, find

I am trying to make my bash script smart. I have some code that is doing a clean up of 10000's of files. What I am trying to work out is how can I find all files that have a bunch of letters a-z or A-Z in front of 0901*.*

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -regextype posix-extended -regex '[a-z]\(0901).*'
```

`find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -regextype posix-extended -regex '[a-z]*.*'`
returns everything

while 
`find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -regextype posix-extended -regex '[a-z]\(0901).*'`
returns nothing.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Comment: Why not just `-name '*0901*.*'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With -regex returning the entire path (relatively as the case may be), need to take ./ into account.  So, borrowing heavily from Tim's answer.

`find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -regextype sed -regex '.*[A-Za-z]\+\(0901\).*'`

Answer (score 1):

The following option should work with `sed` as the regex engine:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -regextype sed -regex "[A-Za-z]\+0901.*"
```

I am interpreting `a bunch of letters` as one or more letter, hence I used `[A-Za-z]+` in front of the digits.  You should not need parentheses here, but if you wanted to use them, you would have to escape those via backslash:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -regextype sed -regex "[A-Za-z]\+\(0901\).*"
```

Comment: Yes I have a bunch of letters in front of the 0901. i have tried both commands and they return nothing. ex of files is trm090123.rtf  abc090123.rtf  zob08110820.rtf

Comment: @goced I think that `+` also needs to be escaped via backslash, q.v. my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use this regex:

```
"[A-Za-z]0901"
```

Good Luck!

Comment: in normal regex  the answer is [a-zA-Z_]+0901.  But in Bash script it is different. still trying to get the syntax correct